# Access all tables/packages of schema1 from schema2?

Tags: oracle

I want to access all tables and packages of schema1 from schema2.
I have given grants too. Like below.

```
grant execute on hr.GetName_Proc_IN to hr2;
```

By this i can able to execute like this with "hr."

```
begin
hr.UnitTest_RnD_PKG.GetName_Proc_IN('Hi','Welcome');
end;
```

But i don't want to use "hr." and want to execute like below :

```
begin
UnitTest_RnD_PKG.GetName_Proc_IN('Hi','Welcome');
end;
```

It is throwing ERROR.
Is there anyway i can do like this .. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a synonym in schema1:

```
create synonym UnitTest_RnD_PKG for hr.UnitTest_RnD_PKG
```

If you don't want to type this by hand for a lot of objects you might create a sql-script by using this query:

```
select 'create synonym ' || object_name || ' for ' || owner || '.' || object_name || ';'
  from dba_objects
  where object_type in ('PACKAGE','TABLE')
    and owner = 'schema2'
```

or create a procedure to create the synonyms from the catalog.

Comment: Thanks .. Is this the only way .. Sorry i am just curious to know .. creating synonym one by one for all tables and packages .. i dont think it is easy . Please help me if there any other way. Thanks for the reply .